# JQuery textarea not submiting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have failed to find a solution to my problem so i need some assistance. I have a form submitting data through Ajax to my database but for some reason, data from textarea is not being sent to the database. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="update_home">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- CKEditor Container -->
        <textarea name="detail" id="js-ckeditor"> <?php print $getDetails->details; ?></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php print $getDetails->hid; ?>" name="hid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit">Update Data</button>
        <div class="mt-2">
            <div class="loading"></div>
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    //show the loader
    $('.loading').html(loader).fadeIn();
    var detail = $('#js-ckeditor').val();
    var hid = $('input[name=hid]').val();
    //organize the data properly
    var form_data =
        'detail=' + detail +
        '&hid=' + hid;
    //disabled all the text fields
    $('.text').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

**PHP**

```
$details = $db - > real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
$db->query("UPDATE home SET details = '$details' WHERE hid = ".$_POST['hid']."");

if ($db->error) {
    echo $db - > error;
} else {
    echo '1';
}
```

Comment: if you are using ckeditr, than use  CKEDITOR.instances.DSC.getData();

Comment: can show error?

Comment: @Orgilv I have been playing around with this line ` var detail = $('#js-ckeditor').val();` and somehow i was getting error `undefined`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra can you show me how

Comment: are you using simple text area or with CK Editor?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra am using CKEDITOR

Comment: is your function calling properly?

Comment: probably you need to change you button type. after that it will work

Answer (score 0):

As @DevisOdedra suggested, i have edited this line to catch data using CKEDITOR inbuilt instance handler from;

```
var detail = $('#js-ckeditor').val();
```

To

```
var detail = CKEDITOR.instances['js-ckeditor'].getData();
```